# Making a quiz with timer on java

Tags: java, timer

I am making a timed quiz where there should be a timer on each question.

I want my code to output a question for 20 seconds and ask for an input for the answer and when the time is up, question number 2 should show up. I am stuck on what should I do to have that, a reference is enough, I just don't know what to read on about, I am using `java.util.Timer` and `TimerTask`.

I also tried

`ExecutorService` but i only see examples that it shutsdown after the timer, i need to post another question after the timer ends, not shotdown the program since i need a time limit for each question and not a timer for the whole quiz.

I tried this

```
if(seconds<=20)
{
    question1();
}
else if (seconds<=40||seconds>=21)
{
    new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
    question2();
}
```

I also tried using while

```
while(seconds<=20){
    question1();
}
while(seconds<=40||seconds>=21){
    new ProcessBuilder("cmd","/c","cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
    question2();
}
```

This is what my question method looks like.

```
public static void question2(String... args) throws 
    IOException, InterruptedException
{  
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.printf("%72s\n","QUIZ FOR PHILIPPINE HISTORY");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.printf("%64s\n","Question #2");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t     WHO DISCOVERED PHILIPPINES?");
    System.out.println("\n\t\t\t\t\t\tA. Fernando Magellan");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t\tB. Ferdinand Megallan");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t\tC. Ferdinand Magellan");
    System.out.println("\t\t\t\t\t\tD. Fernando Poe");

    System.out.println("\n\t\t\t\t\t\tTYPE YOU ANSWER HERE: ");
    char answer2 = a.nextLine().charAt(0);
    switch (sagot2)
    {
        case 'B':
        case 'b':
            score++;
            seconds = 21;
            System.out.print("You are CORRECT!");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.print("You are WRONG");
            seconds = 21;
            break;
    }
}
```

This is the beginning of my code plus the timer and timertask.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
public class q2 {
static int seconds = 0; 
static Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);
static Timer timer = new Timer();
static int number = 1;
static int score = 0;
public static void mema(){
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask () 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            seconds++;
            System.out.print(seconds);
        }
    };

    timer.schedule(task,1000,1000);
}
```

I also tried using this but it doesnt do the other method after 5 seconds.

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
long wait = 5000;
long end = start + wait;
long end1 = end + wait;

while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end)
{
question1();
}
while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end1 || System.currentTimeMillis() > end)
{
question2();
}
```

Comment: You're missing a closing brace `}` after the body of your `if(seconds<=20)`

Comment: @Michael thanks! i edited it, but still not running as i wanted though.

Answer (score 1):

Various things that you did make your code more complicated then it ought to.

First of all, avoid **fixing** details such as "this is the first question" versus "this is the second question".

Instead: focus on **basic** elements that you need. In your case: you want to display a question for a certain amount of time. Afterwards, the program should either display another question - or probably give a summary and end.

Thus: write a class/method that simply puts up a question and then waits. And then think how you could re-use that code to put up *any number* of questions in sequence.

For the "timing": given the fact that you are a beginner, I would recommend you to not go "fully multi-threaded" (meaning: tasks, and schedulers) at this point. Instead, "waiting for some time" can easily be achieved via

- getting the currentTime
- endTime = currentTime + 20 sec
- looping until that endTime is reached

Thing is: you learn programming by exploring your options and trying many things. Thus I gave you *hints* - not code.

Comment: I edited my post, i tried using currenttimemillis but after 5 seconds, it wont proceed to the next while, can i get your guidance again?

Comment: i think it is still waiting for my input in order to proceed to the next method, what can i do to cancel my first method after the time limit?

Comment: sir can i still please ask you this question? im still stucked after days of reading and trying something, i still dont know how to stop my first method after the time limit.